# local variable in if statement javascript

Tags: javascript

```
var request = require('request');
var cheerio = require('request');
var eval = "5555";

request('http://google.com', function (error, response, body) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
        var keys = body.split(",");
        eval = keys[0]; // Think keys[0] is 7777
// and no problem in if statement, it must be excuted.
    }
})

console.log("evalue :"+eval);
// result ---> 5555
```

Why the result is 5555? not 7777? I think eval is global value, and if statement will update eval value to 7777, and I think the result will be 7777 but I realize it doesn't. Can anyone tell me why. Sorry to similar question.

Comment: `request` is async.  So, your console.log fires *before* the callback.

Comment: `require` isn't part of plain JavaScript. What else does this need to be tagged with?

Answer (score 2):

The callback in `request` is *asynchronous*.

Therefore, when you call `console.log`, it is before the `request` callback is executed. Try logging in the callback itself

```
request('http://google.com', function (error, response, body) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
        var keys = body.split(",");
        eval = keys[0]; // Think keys[0] is 7777
        console.log("evalue :"+eval);
    }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You are doing an asynchronous task.
The callback function does not necessarily runs before the `console.log`.

This is the nature of javascript non-blocking IO. When you need to do an IO operation, you can pass a callback, when the IO finishes, it will invoke your callback, meanwhile CPU is free to do other procedures in your JS file.

Answer (score 0):

Because `console.log` is executed before above request's response has arrived since this is an asynchronous execution. Try putting the `console.log` inside that anonymous function to get the value you want.

```
request('http://google.com', function (error, response, body) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
        var keys = body.split(",");
        eval = keys[0]; // Think keys[0] is 7777
        console.log(eval);
    }
})
```